# DAX function to retire low balance account holder name

Tags: powerbi, dax

| Account Holder Name | Balance |
| --- | --- |
| Balu | 3 |
| venugopal | 8 |
| karthik | 10 |

**OUTPUT:**
Balu

**Required DAX code to get account holder name who maintains low balance in their account**

*In the above table balu maintains low balance in the account*

Comment: You could just use a slicer based on balancelevel or a visual/page filter with the balance from which point it is perceived as low. You don't need dax for this in my opinion.

Comment: Need to use DAX function since in real time data.... their are round 1K account holder names . That I cannot manage through slicer

Comment: That would've been good information to include in your original question. The more information you give, the better answers you'll get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is the following `measure`:

```
Account_Low_Balance =
LOOKUPVALUE (
    'Table'[Account Holder Name],
    'Table'[Balance], MIN ( 'Table'[Balance] )
)
```